# Show the "Yes" value when the search ID is matched with other ID list and if these ID has at least one "Yes" value

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of ID and Yes/No values.
What I want to show is to get the "Yes" value if this ID has at least one "Yes" in the original list.
I used this formula and I think this is not working really.

```
=INDEX(A:B,IF(MATCH(F2,A:A,0),MATCH("Yes",B:B)),2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for `SUMPRODUCT`. Copy this to cell `G2` and pull it down:

```
IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$5=$F2)*($B$2:$B$5="Yes"))>0,"Yes","No")
```